# jquery from external file not loading

Tags: javascript, jquery, external

So I know this question has been asked many times but I can't seem to get this working, even though it looks correct to me.  My jquery functions from an external file aren't loading properly.

My tableMethods.js external file looks like

```
$(function(){

// Write FITS
function writeFits(){
    var data = $('.sastable').bootstrapTable('getData');
    var name = $('#fitsname').val();
    $.getJSON($SCRIPT_ROOT + '/writeFits', {'data':JSON.stringify(data),'name':name}, 
        function(data){
            $('#fitsout').text(data.result);
        }); 
}

// Delete rows from data table
function deleteRows(){
    var $table = $('.sastable');
    var $delete = $('#delete'); 

    var ids = $.map($table.bootstrapTable('getSelections'), function (row) {
            return row.id
    });

    $table.bootstrapTable('remove', {
            field: 'id',
            values: ids
    });
}

})
```

My html header looks like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/bootstrap-table.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src="/static/js/tableMethods.js"></script>
```

When I check the inspector, it says the file has loaded yet when I click my button that looks like

```
<button id="delete" class="btn btn-danger" type='button' onClick='deleteRows()'>Delete Rows</button>
```

I get the error

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: deleteRows is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a scoping problem. You have to move your functions outside of `$(function() { ... })`

In JavaScript, anything exclusively defined within a function, generally stays within a function:

```
var x = 3;

(function() {
    var y = 1;
})();

console.log(x); // 3
console.log(y); // error
```

So if you’re defining a function within a function, you can only invoke it from that function you have defined it in. When trying to invoke it from anywhere else, the inner function will seem undefined.

In your case, you can simply remove the wrapper function:

```
$(function() { // Delete this...

    ...

}); // And this
```

For more information, read [You Don’t Know JS: Scope & Closures](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/scope%20%26%20closures)

Comment: I've tried that as well and it didn't work either.  My original tableMethods.js had only the function calls inside the file.  When it didn't work, I thought I needed to wait until the DOM was loaded, so I added the outer function.

Comment: @havok2063 Could you give a little more information? At what line is the error thrown? Screenshots and more code would be very helpful.

Comment: Hi.  Well I think I got it to work.  I took out the outer function as you suggested, and I changed all of my /static/js sources to ../static/js, and then I made sure the actual js and page refreshed.  I think my page was still using an older version of my js file.